# How to use ks.test in a certain range

Tags: r, statistics

I like to test a range of values if they follow a unif. But I dont know how, e.g.

```
x<-runif(1000)
ks.test(x, punif,alternative = "two.sided")
```

is working, but

```
x<-runif(1000)
ks.test(x[x<0.5], punif,alternative = "two.sided")
```

gives no meaningful results. how to use punif in the ks.test for a correct test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you consider "not meaningful". The reported p-value was effectively 0. It was telling you that the values restricted to 0-0.5 were not likely to have been randomly drawn from a uniform distribution on the domain of 0-1. Contrast with:

```
> x<-runif(1000)
> ks.test(x[x<0.5], function(x) {punif(x, 0, 0.5)},alternative = "two.sided")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x[x < 0.5]
D = 0.0292, p-value = 0.7837
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```